# Wordpress list results from wp_users and wp_usermeta

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

I am writing a plugin which grabs an array of data from the wordpress database using...

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users", ARRAY_A);
```

This works fine and I can display all the info from the users table, the issue I have is that I need to also pull out the First name and Last name which are in the wp_usermeta table.

Is there a way to modify the statement to also pull those details from the other table?

Comment: This may be possible, but the query will be pretty complex because you're essentially trying to pull two separate meta keys for each user and group them together. Also, First and Last name fields are often not set...by default WordPress uses the display_name field in the wp_users table (setting that is required for a user profile, while first and last names are not). Would that not work for your plugin's purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in one query and not necessarily the slickest either, but the following will produce what you want:

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users", ARRAY_A);  
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $single) {
    $meta = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT meta_value
        FROM $wpdb->usermeta
        WHERE user_id = $single[ID]
        AND (meta_key = 'first_name' OR meta_key = 'last_name')
        ORDER BY meta_key",
        ARRAY_A
    );
    $data[$i]['first_name'] = $meta[0]['meta_value'];
    $data[$i]['last_name'] = $meta[1]['meta_value'];
    $i++;
}
```

**EDIT:** Here it is in one query:

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT $wpdb->users.*,
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value
            ORDER BY $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key
            SEPARATOR ' '
        ) AS name
    FROM $wpdb->users
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta
    ON $wpdb->users.ID = $wpdb->usermeta.user_id
    WHERE ($wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name'
        OR $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = 'last_name')
    GROUP BY $wpdb->users.ID",
    ARRAY_A
);
```

Note that opposed to the first version, the latter does not produce `$data[x]['first_name']` and  `$data[x]['last_name']`, but  `$data[x]['name']` instead. This is due to either being stored in the "meta_value" column. It is not possible to accomplish your task in one query and store the first and last name in two different array keys at the same time.

Hence, if doing it the second way, you'd have to use php's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function later on to access the name. Or correct it in a loop after the query has been run:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $single) {
    $name_parts = explode(' ', $single['name']);
    $data[$i]['first_name'] = $name_parts[0];
    $data[$i]['last_name'] = $name_parts[1];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: That is perfect, just what I was trying to achieve.  The JOIN function was really confusing me but now I have seen it laid out for my example it all makes sense!  Is there a way to limit the returned results to just subscribers or would that need to be done separately?

Comment: @fightstarr20 That's also not trivial, especially in one query, because the capability information is once again stored in the _meta\_value_ column of the _wp\_usermeta_ table. If I find the time tonight, I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi Johannes,  thanks for looking at this.  I have managed to include the wp_user_level field in the array results so I can now differentiate between user levels.  I guess i just need to know how to only include results that have wp_user_level=>0 in the array

Comment: I still haven't managed to acheieve this, any chance you could take a look at adding the user level in?